# Virtualbox uninstalling problem 16.04

Tags: apt, 16.04, virtualbox, uninstall

I have virtualbox, i don't remember how i did download it. I want to update, so i am going to delete this version. To use my virtualbox i type `virtualbox` in terminal, but when i type `sudo apt-get remove virtualbox` it says;

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'virtualbox' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

So how am i supposed to uninstall it?

Comment: In terminal, type: "dpkg -l *virtualbox*", without the quotes, and that'll tell you the correct name to use. It's probably something like "virtualbox-5.0".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the following commands:

```
$ whereis vbox
```

copy all the folders in the output

```
$ sudo rm -rf (all the folders)

$ whereis virtualbox
```

copy all the folders in the output

```
$ sudo rm -rf (all folders)

$ sudo apt-get remove virtualbox-* --purge
```

This is how i removed it. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 9):

Depending on your version... try this command

```
sudo apt-get remove VirtualBox-5.1
```

Find your version by launching the app, then select Help->About. You will get a long version number (eg. 5.1.18r114002). Ignore anything past the second decimal point; in my case it is version "5.1".

Comment: Did you test this by any chance?

Comment: This solution works. I tested it on my Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: It worked for me, Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

The package is not called **Virtualbox** probably.  One way to find out the name is to type

`aptitude search virtualbox*`

in a terminal and it's going to show you all the virtualbox related packages including the one installed.  Installed packages begin with letter **i**.

Another way is to use **synaptic** and type **virtualbox** in the search box.  It will show you how the installed packages are called.

Comment: There is only one which is unity-scope-virtualbox and it is 76kb. So how can i delete all of it? And in synaptic's search, for virtualbox it said no packages. I just realiazed Ubuntu software thinks virtualbox is not installed.

Comment: You have to remember how you installed it.  If it's not listed, you probaly didn't use a .deb package.

Comment: How many ways are there to install a package?

Comment: deb packages, snaps, compile from source.

Comment: A lot, i guess :) http://askubuntu.com/questions/445903/what-are-the-different-ways-to-install-a-software-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

If you have manually installed the Virtualbox package from Oracle's website, use this:

```
sudo dpkg -r virtualbox-5.2
```

Change the "5.2" for the version that you have installed.

If you need to check the virtualbox version installed in you pc, use this:

```
dpkg-query --show |grep -i virtualbox
```

Comment: This is what I needed as I downloaded the installer from VirtualBox's web site, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't install it from the repsoitories and you can't find it with `dpkg -l` you may have obtained it from the [Oracle website](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) and installed it manually. If so, this quote from section 2.3.3.4 (Pg 40) of [the manual](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.1.18/UserManual.pdf) relates to your situation.

```
Before updating or uninstalling VirtualBox, you must terminate any virtual machines which are
currently running and exit the VirtualBox or VBoxSVC applications. To update VirtualBox, simply
run the installer of the updated version. To uninstall VirtualBox, invoke the installer like this:
sudo ./VirtualBox.run uninstall
or as root
./VirtualBox.run uninstall
. Starting with version 2.2.2, you can uninstall the .run package by invoking
/opt/VirtualBox/uninstall.sh
To manually uninstall VirtualBox, simply undo the steps in the manual installation in reverse
order.
```